# I want to search business categories in FQL

Tags: facebook-fql

Can I use "like" syntax in the query? or I need to input the exactly same value. If so can you guys give me a example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the object id in your sql to retrieve the desired data.

Check this link. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/